# Footer issue with prestashop theme on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, footer, prestashop-1.5

My footer is not displayed correctly on chrome but OK with other browsers.
I use a paid theme on my prestashop install but they tell me it's a module issue what i don't belive.

Link to the website : obfuscated
Printscreen of the bug can be found here [obfuscated/issue.PNG](http://klek.ch/issue.PNG)
Here is the CSS footer part

```
#footer {height:198px;clear:both;background:url(../img/bg_footer.png) 0 0 repeat-x;}
.footer {width:1000px;margin:0 auto;position:relative;}
.footer a {color:#656464;text-decoration:none;}
.footer a:hover {color:#e61c23;}

a.mobile {display:none;}


.footer > div {width:190px;float:left;padding:0 10px 0 0;}
.footer > div h4 {padding:16px 0 0 0;font:bold 12px "Arial";color:#404041;text-transform:uppercase;}

.footer > div ul {}
.footer > div ul li {margin:4px 0 0 0;}
.footer > div ul li + li {margin:5px 0 0 0;}
```

Any help would be highly appreciate!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another footer and height problem ;) Could you please change wrapper2 height to auto;

```
#wrapper2 {
height: auto;
background: url(../img/bg_img.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;
}
```